# How to Get Array Inside stdClass

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode with json
http://digitsolutions4u.com/apps_services/statuslist.php?catid=1
like this

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://digitsolutions4u.com/apps_services/statuslist.php?catid=1";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

i want to get all "statusdesc" Values after decode.
I am getting results something like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [statusid] => 1329
                    [statusdesc] => love86.jpg
                )
)
)
```

i just want to list out all statusdesc available on the page like 
love86.jpg
love87.jpg
love88.jpg
and so on. Anyone can provide me solution(code)  for this? I have tried several threads, but no success.

Comment: one important note is just use to `json_decode` alone, avoid string manupulations on your json string (just like what you did with that `str_replace`),

Comment: use json_decode($response_string,true);  and array_column()

Answer (score 2):

By default `json_decode` decodes it to an object instead of an associative array. You just access the members of that object via the arrow (`->`) notation. To get each post you can use `foreach` to loop through them.

```
foreach ($data->posts as $post) {
  echo $post->statusdesc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is tell `json_decode()` that you want it to convert the JSON String to all arrays and not as the JSONString intended an object

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://digitsolutions4u.com/apps_services/statuslist.php?catid=1";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);

$data = json_decode($json, true);
// the change ..  ..  ..   ^^^^

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
foreach ($json['posts'] as $post) {
    echo $post['statusdesc'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

However is is simpler tp deal with it as it is and do

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://digitsolutions4u.com/apps_services/statuslist.php?catid=1";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);

$data = json_decode($json);

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($data);
//echo "</pre>";

foreach ($json->posts as $post) {
    echo $post->statusdesc . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode()` with second parameter `true` . it's return the json string as associative array . and use `array_column` like this

```
<?php

    $response ='{"posts":[{"statusid":"1329","statusdesc":"love86.jpg"},{"statusid":"1328","statusdesc":"love85.jpg"},{"statusid":"1327","statusdesc":"love84.jpg"},{"statusid":"1326","statusdesc":"love83.jpg"},{"statusid":"1325","statusdesc":"love82.jpg"},{"statusid":"1324","statusdesc":"love81.jpg"},{"statusid":"1323","statusdesc":"love80.jpg"},{"statusid":"1322","statusdesc":"love79.jpg"},{"statusid":"1321","statusdesc":"love78.jpg"},{"statusid":"1320","statusdesc":"love77.jpg"},{"statusid":"1319","statusdesc":"love76.jpg"},{"statusid":"1318","statusdesc":"love75.jpg"},{"statusid":"1317","statusdesc":"love74.jpg"},{"statusid":"1316","statusdesc":"love73.jpg"},{"statusid":"1315","statusdesc":"love72.jpg"},{"statusid":"1314","statusdesc":"love71.jpg"},{"statusid":"1313","statusdesc":"love70.jpg"},{"statusid":"1312","statusdesc":"love69.jpg"},{"statusid":"1311","statusdesc":"love68.jpg"},{"statusid":"1310","statusdesc":"love67.jpg"},{"statusid":"1287","statusdesc":"love66.jpg"},{"statusid":"1286","statusdesc":"love65.jpg"},{"statusid":"1285","statusdesc":"love64.jpg"},{"statusid":"1284","statusdesc":"love63.jpg"},{"statusid":"1283","statusdesc":"love62.jpg"},{"statusid":"1282","statusdesc":"love61.jpg"},{"statusid":"1204","statusdesc":"love60.jpg"},{"statusid":"1203","statusdesc":"love59.jpg"},{"statusid":"1202","statusdesc":"love58.jpg"},{"statusid":"1201","statusdesc":"love57.jpg"},{"statusid":"1200","statusdesc":"love56.jpg"},{"statusid":"1199","statusdesc":"love55.jpg"},{"statusid":"1045","statusdesc":"love54.jpg"},{"statusid":"1044","statusdesc":"love53.jpg"},{"statusid":"1043","statusdesc":"love52.jpg"},{"statusid":"1042","statusdesc":"love51.jpg"},{"statusid":"1004","statusdesc":"love50.jpg"},{"statusid":"1003","statusdesc":"love49.jpg"},{"statusid":"1002","statusdesc":"love48.jpg"},{"statusid":"1001","statusdesc":"love47.jpg"},{"statusid":"1000","statusdesc":"love46.jpg"},{"statusid":"239","statusdesc":"love45.jpg"},{"statusid":"238","statusdesc":"love44.jpg"},{"statusid":"237","statusdesc":"love43.jpg"},{"statusid":"236","statusdesc":"love42.jpg"},{"statusid":"235","statusdesc":"love41.jpg"},{"statusid":"234","statusdesc":"love40.jpg"},{"statusid":"233","statusdesc":"love39.jpg"},{"statusid":"232","statusdesc":"love38.jpg"},{"statusid":"231","statusdesc":"love37.jpg"},{"statusid":"230","statusdesc":"love36.jpg"},{"statusid":"229","statusdesc":"love35.jpg"},{"statusid":"228","statusdesc":"love34.jpg"},{"statusid":"227","statusdesc":"love33.jpg"},{"statusid":"226","statusdesc":"love32.jpg"},{"statusid":"31","statusdesc":"love31.jpg"},{"statusid":"30","statusdesc":"love30.jpg"},{"statusid":"29","statusdesc":"love29.jpg"},{"statusid":"28","statusdesc":"love28.jpg"},{"statusid":"27","statusdesc":"love27.jpg"},{"statusid":"26","statusdesc":"love26.jpg"},{"statusid":"25","statusdesc":"love25.jpg"},{"statusid":"24","statusdesc":"love24.jpg"},{"statusid":"23","statusdesc":"love23.jpg"},{"statusid":"22","statusdesc":"love22.jpg"},{"statusid":"21","statusdesc":"love21.jpg"},{"statusid":"20","statusdesc":"love20.jpg"},{"statusid":"19","statusdesc":"love19.jpg"},{"statusid":"18","statusdesc":"love18.jpg"},{"statusid":"17","statusdesc":"love17.jpg"},{"statusid":"16","statusdesc":"love16.jpg"},{"statusid":"15","statusdesc":"love15.jpg"},{"statusid":"14","statusdesc":"love14.jpg"},{"statusid":"13","statusdesc":"love13.jpg"},{"statusid":"12","statusdesc":"love12.jpg"},{"statusid":"11","statusdesc":"love11.jpg"},{"statusid":"10","statusdesc":"love10.jpg"},{"statusid":"9","statusdesc":"love9.jpg"},{"statusid":"8","statusdesc":"love8.jpg"},{"statusid":"7","statusdesc":"love7.jpg"},{"statusid":"6","statusdesc":"love6.jpg"},{"statusid":"5","statusdesc":"love5.jpg"},{"statusid":"4","statusdesc":"love4.jpg"},{"statusid":"3","statusdesc":"love3.jpg"},{"statusid":"2","statusdesc":"love2.jpg"},{"statusid":"1","statusdesc":"love1.jpg"}]}';

    $response_array = json_decode($response,true);

    $final_res =  array_column($response_array['posts'],'statusdesc');

    print_r($final_res);

?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => love86.jpg
    [1] => love85.jpg
    [2] => love84.jpg
    [3] => love83.jpg
    [4] => love82.jpg
    [5] => love81.jpg
    [6] => love80.jpg
    ......
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_url = "http://digitsolutions4u.com/apps_services/statuslist.php?catid=1";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
```

this should return you array of object(stdClass)

```
$elm = json_decode( $json );
var_dump( $elm->posts );
```

you can get one of your string in this way:

```
$elm->posts[5]->statusdesc
```

or you can convert your json into array using json_decode( $json, true )

NOTE: json_decode can't remember your original class as serialize it always return stdClass (you can access to properties but not to the methods of the original class)